# Google Feed API - not returning feed URLs

Tags: json, rss, google-api, google-feed-api

When I use the Google Feed API's `find` search, a lot of the time it's not returning the URLs of the feed.

As an example, a `find` search for the query 'CNN', points to this URL:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=cnn

And returns these results (trimmed):

```
{
  "responseData": {
    "query": "cnn",
    "entries": [
      {
        "url": "",
        "title": "<b>CNN</b>.com: Breaking News, US, World, Weather, Entertainment <b>...</b>",
        "contentSnippet": "Find the latest breaking news and information on the top stories, weather, <br>\nbusiness, entertainment, politics, and more. For in-depth coverage, <b>CNN</b> <br>\nprovides&nbsp;...",
        "link": "http://www.cnn.com/"
      },
      {
        "url": "",
        "title": "World News - International Headlines, Stories and Video - <b>CNN</b>.com",
        "contentSnippet": "<b>CNN</b> brings you International News stories, video and headlines from Europe, <br>\nAsia, Africa, the Middle East, and the Americas.",
        "link": "http://www.cnn.com/world"
      },
      {
        "url": "",
        "title": "U.S. News - Headlines, Stories and Video - <b>CNN</b>.com",
        "contentSnippet": "<b>CNN</b>.com brings you US News, Videos and Stories from around the country.",
        "link": "http://www.cnn.com/us"
      },
      {
        "url": "",
        "title": "<b>CNN</b> (@<b>CNN</b>) | Twitter",
        "contentSnippet": "The latest Tweets from <b>CNN</b> (@<b>CNN</b>). It&#39;s our job to #GoThere and tell the most <br>\ndifficult stories. Come with us!",
        "link": "https://twitter.com/cnn"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/CNN/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile",
        "title": "<b>CNN</b> - YouTube",
        "contentSnippet": "<b>CNN</b> operates as a division of Turner Broadcasting System, which is a subsidiary <br>\nof Time Warner. <b>CNN</b> identifies itself as -- and is widely known to be - the m...",
        "link": "http://www.youtube.com/user/CNN"
      }
    ]
  },
  "responseDetails": null,
  "responseStatus": 200
}
```

The first 4 results don't have a URL attached. The 5th one does, but isn't relevant, so my initial idea to remove items with empty URLs wouldn't work.

Following the basic query example on their [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#findBasic), their example shows the `url` field of the results filled in. Copy and pasting [the URL they provided](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs) shows similar results, but without the `url` field filled out.

Unless I'm mistaken, this seems like it must be a problem with Google's results.

Comment: I'd bet Google either scrapes content for those feeds or is provided data via an agreement with CNN rather than RSS.

Comment: No, this happens across searches for Fox, BBC, and in their own example the results differ in the same way too.

Comment: This API is no longer available.